# PHP - How do we can get Youtube Views and comments count along with videos list via Youtube APIs?

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

I am getting list of videos from youtube API. I want to also get views and comment count in response from youtube apis.

I am trying the following.

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('API code samples');
$client->setDeveloperKey('api_key');
echo "<pre>";
$queryParams = [
    'channelId' => 'channel_id',
    'maxResults' => 5,
    'order' => 'date',
    'type' => 'video'
];

$response = $service->search->listSearch('snippet', $queryParams);
print_r($response);
```

**Youtube API Response**

```
[snippet] => Google\Service\YouTube\SearchResultSnippet Object
    (
        [channelId] => Channel_id
        [channelTitle] => João Patrício
        [description] => Mohamed Said made an amazing video demonstrating how to easily develop a Nuxt and Laravel API application, and now let's ...
        [liveBroadcastContent] => none
        [publishedAt] => 2021-12-08T08:57:21Z
        [thumbnailsType:protected] => Google\Service\YouTube\ThumbnailDetails
        [thumbnailsDataType:protected] => 
        [title] => Deploying LaravelAPI and NuxtJs App using Traefik and Docker - 2nd Episode
```

I am getting vidoes title, description etc
is it possible to get video's views & comments count in same api response?

Help me pls. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### I am getting vidoes title, description etc is it possible to get video's views & comments count in same api response?

No it is not posible.

##### Search.list method

You are using the [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method Which returns a list of [search#resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource)

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": {
    "kind": string,
    "videoId": string,
    "channelId": string,
    "playlistId": string
  },
  "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": datetime,
    "channelId": string,
    "title": string,
    "description": string,
    "thumbnails": {
      (key): {
        "url": string,
        "width": unsigned integer,
        "height": unsigned integer
      }
    },
    "channelTitle": string,
    "liveBroadcastContent": string
  }
}
```

##### Video.list method

To get a rating back you would need to use [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) which will return a [video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource)
which does contain the stats your are looking for.

```
  "statistics": {
    "viewCount": unsigned long,
    "likeCount": unsigned long,
    "dislikeCount": unsigned long,
    "favoriteCount": unsigned long,
    "commentCount": unsigned long
  },
```

Comment: so we have to execute another request per video. Thank you for the help